# Best way to compare variables between instances of the same class?

Tags: c#, arrays, contains

This is a game based on certain elemental combos, I'm trying to find a way to have two elements compare to each other in order to reduce hard coding. I do have a working solution provided at the end, but I'm  trying to learn any ways that would be more simple, straight forward, and readable.

```
//Wizard is a class
Wizard player1;
Wizard player2;

player1.health = 3;
player2.health = 3;

//Elements is an enum that allows fire/water/air to be selected
player1.elementSelected = Elements.fire;
player2.elementSelected = Elements.water;

Wizard[] bothPlayers = { player1, player2 };
```

I want to search for the active element in bothPlayers so I can effect the Player's health. I know this doesn't work, but I was wondering if I could do something like:

```
if (bothPlayers.Contains(Wizard.elementSelected.Elements.fire) && bothPlayers.Contains(Wizard.elementSelected.Elements.water))
```

Alternatively I was thinking of just setting it to a new array but that wont let me call back to effect player health unless I set them up to a new variable like:

```
    Elements[] bothSelectedElements = { player1.elementSelected, player2.elementSelected };

    if (bothSelectedElements.Contains(Elements.fire) && bothSelectedElements.Contains(Elements.water))
    {
        Wizard playerWithFire; // = player who selected fire. Can't set without hardcoding
        Wizard playerWithWater; // = player who selected water. Can't set without hardcoding

        playerWithFire.health--;
        playerWithWater.waterStrength++;
    }
```

//***CURRENT WORKING SOLUTION***

```
//set each Wizard container to null at the start of each check
Wizard fire = null;
Wizard water = null;
Wizard air = null;

//add check to make sure same elements aren't selected. Then assign the players to the containers
foreach (Wizard player in bothPlayers)
{
    if (player.elementSelected == Elements.fire)
    {
        fire = player;
    }
    if (player.elementSelected == Elements.water)
    {
        water = player;
    }
    if (player.elementSelected == Elements.air)
    {
        air = player;
    }
}

//then do the actual check
if (fire != null && water != null)
{
    fire.health--;
    water.waterStrength++;
}
//repeat with other if statement comparisons
```

Comment: Is bothPlayers always 2 players? or could it be more?

Comment: oops sorry @LarsTech.. that was just a copy paste error... just edited it

Comment: @MatthewEskolin currently it is only 2 players, but I'm trying to keep it open ended in case I decide to implement more players later. Trying to avoid hardcoding, but if I need to commit to 2 players thats fine as well

Comment: This question would probably fit better at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

This is a fiddly problem, but thankfully you are working with a language that has all the tools you need to hide the complexity away.

```
var elementWizards = wizards.GroupBy(w => w.elementSelected).ToDictionary(g => g.Key);

var elements = elementWizards.Keys.ToHashSet(); // gives us access to SetEquals

if (elements.SetEquals(new[] { Elements.Fire, Elements.Water }))
{
    foreach (var wizard in elementWizards[Elements.Fire]) wizard.health--;
    foreach (var wizard in elementWizards[Elements.Water]) wizard.waterStrength++;
}
else if (elements.SetEquals(new[] { Elements.Earth, Elements.Fire }))
{
    // more effects...
}
```

Note that `SetEquals` doesn't care about the order of items, so you don't need to worry about handling water/fire instead of fire/water.

Footnote: in the real world I would define some static `HashSet<Element>` objects and call `if(foo.SetEquals(elementWizards.Keys))`, but I kept things simple for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Linq:

1. Check if there are water and fire wizard (with Linq)
2. Foreach to search and add health etc...

   ```
           if (bothPlayers.Count(wizard => wizard.elementSelected == Elements.fire) > 0 &&
           bothPlayers.Count(wizard => wizard.elementSelected == Elements.water) > 0)
       {
           bothPlayers.ForEach(wizard =>
           {
               var _ = wizard.elementSelected == Elements.water ? wizard.waterStrength++ : 
                       wizard.elementSelected == Elements.fire ? wizard.health-- : 1;
           });
       }
   ```

you can change the wizards you are searching for and the properties that depends on it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of finding item in a collection. For example :

```
// using Array.Find method
Wizard fire = Array.Find(bothPlayers, player => player.elementSelected == Elements.fire);

// or using System.Linq FirstOrDefault extension
Wizard water = bothPlayers.FirstOrDefault(player => player.elementSelected == Elements.water);

if (fire != null && water != null)
{
    fire.health--;
    water.waterStrength++;
}
```

---

For more than two players, a `Lookup` can be used to separate the players into groups :

```
var lookup = bothPlayers.ToLookup(player => player.elementSelected);

if (lookup.Contains(Elements.fire) && lookup.Contains(Elements.water))
{
    foreach (Wizard fire  in lookup[Elements.fire] ) fire.health--;
    foreach (Wizard water in lookup[Elements.water]) water.waterStrength++;
}
```